# Finding the value of a variable from a question.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is as follow:
-Mum,Dad and 3 children went to buy tickets for amusement park. The total price they paid was 1400$, if the children tickets cost half the adults. Find the price of an adult ticket.

Comment: What I did was multiply 1400 by 2 because 2 adults and divided it by 5 the total. But that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let the price of an adult ticket be $x$ dollars. Then, the price of a child ticket will be $\frac x2$ dollars. There are two adults and three children. The prices add up to $1400$ dollars.

Can you solve from here?

> Cost of adult tickets for two $=2\times x=2x$.
>  Cost of three child tickets $=3\times\frac{x}2=\frac{3x}{2}$. Then, $2x+\frac{3x}{2}=1400$. This gives $\frac{7x}{2}=1400$ or $x=400$ dollars.

Comment: Dude I tried everything but nothing worked, could you help me out with ithe :D

Comment: @SubhadeepDey thanks :#)))

Comment: @GoodDeeds thankss :)))

Comment: @W3RM $$2x+\frac{3x}{2}=\frac{4x}{2}+\frac{3x}{2}=\frac{7x}{2}$$

Comment: @GoodDeeds god bless you. Thanks.